# Realtek RTL8723BE wifi card not detected and no internet via Wifi or Wired connection

Tags: networking, drivers, internet, network-manager, realtek

When I am installing Ubuntu I cannot connect to my wifi network.
It keeps trying and finally fails.

After installation I am not able to use internet either via WLan or even if I directly attach the LAN cord of my router to my laptop.

What is going wrong and how do I fix it ?

dkms status output :

```
rtlwifi-new 0.10 4.4.0-21-generic, x86_x64: installed
```

Comment: to install the drivers as mentioned there, I need to have access to internet in some way or the other. I cannot connect to internet either via Wifi or via Lan

Comment: You can download deb package from that PPA and also DKMS package from Ubuntu repos using another comp.

Comment: If you do not know how to do it, tell the Ubuntu version and the arch (32 or 64 bit).

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 is the version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have any internet connection, you can download the package using another computer, a phone, etc.

The package is [HERE](https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi/+files/rtlwifi-new-dkms_0.10_all.deb)

You will also need `DKMS` installed. You can find the DKMS package for Ubuntu 16.04 [HERE](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11_all.deb)

Copy these two files to the Ubuntu Home folder (~/) and run in terminal

```
sudo dpkg -i dkms*.deb rtlwifi*.deb
```

Then reboot.

If a signal is still too weak, run

```
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=2"  | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

and reboot again.

Comment: I did this. Still I cannot connect to my wifi network. It tries to connect for a certain time and then says, disconnected.

Comment: Are you sure the driver is installed? Please post output of `dkms status` to your question.

Comment: added. Plz check

Comment: The driver is installed. You can try to use `ant_sel=2` parameter. See the duplicate answer.

Comment: Gotcha! Working!

Comment: Why not `sudo reboot`?

Comment: Why not just reboot? There is no need to make this kind of edits. A user should be prepared for a reboot, not just run commands. This kind of an edit does not improve anything.

Answer (score -2):

You mentioned that your were unable to connect to net via ethernet port using lan cable from router. so use lspci command to check weather your ethernet card is getting recognized or not(Its displayed as xx.xx.x Ethernet controller. xxxxxx.........). If recognizable the model and driver type will be displayed there itself. so try downloading the drivers manually and install them.

Comment: I am trying to get both working actually.

Comment: The ethernet controller is shown by using lspci